# How to update column with the same name in both tables in join query in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

So there is [update_all](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update_all/3) method in Ecto and from what I know, we are allowed to pass a join query to its. But then I realized that I have column with the same name which caused ambiguity in what column should be updated.

```
Repo.update_all(
  from(d in "dogs",
    inner_join: b in "bones",
    on: b.dog_id == d.id,
    where: d.status != "new",
    where: b.status != "new",
    update: [set: [status: "excellent"]]
  ), []
)
```

This resulted in column `status` from table `dogs` being updated, how can I then update the one from `bones` table?

Comment: did you consider maybe using Ecto [Multi](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#module-example)?

Comment: Why and how? I know Multi but I don't think it is needed here to simple update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By its nature, `update_all` will update the table in the `from` clause. If you want to update more than one table, you'll need to use [`Ecto.Multi`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#module-example)

Comment: Thanks! Btw where do you know it from? I haven't seen this explanation in docs.

Comment: It's the only way that I've ever used it... but you're making me question whether or not that's actually right.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a way to do this purely using SQL, but what we are expecting from Ecto is to make things easier, right?

So, first of all, using a string for the table is acceptable, but you really need to know what you are doing. You are basically circumventing everything Ecto sets up for you to interact with the database.
Usually, what you want is a schema for Dog and a schema for Bone. [Please refer to the excellent Ecto documentation.](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html)

And then we have `Ecto.Multi` which basically collects a bunch of database interactions, and then executes everything in one transaction. [Please look at the Ecto.Multi docs as well](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html) and [pay special attention to Ecto.Multi.update_all/5](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html?#update_all/5)

For example:

```
dog_query = from(
  dogs in Dog,
  dogs.status != "new"
)

bone_query =  from(
  bones in Bone,
  bones.status != "new"
)

Ecto.Multi.new()
|> Ecto.Multi.update_all(:dogs, dog_query, set: [status: "new"])
|> Ecto.Multi.update_all(:bones, bone_query, set: [status: "new"])
|> Repo.transaction()

# I think this returns {:ok, %{dogs: [_all_updated_dogs], bones: [_all_updated_bones]}}
```

This will execute both updates in one transaction, meaning the rows can not be altered while dogs and bones are being updated (using database locks and transactions.)

You can run multis with any kind of `queryable`, so if you insist on using the table name directly, you can go ahead and replace `Dog` with `"dogs"`, but I would recommend using schemas to clarify your schema.

EDIT: and a pet pief of mine, please use the full names in your ecto queries - `d` `b` looks so similar... imagine a big query with `b` `d` `db`, `qd`, etc. what does that stand for? idk! please name your variables.